# What's the most efficient way to combine the image tiles from xckd's Click and Drag into a single composite .png?

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm attempting to combine all of the image tiles from [Click and Drag](http://xckd.com/1110/) using ImageMagick.  It's taking a considerably long time to process.

More generally, if I have collection of greyscale, 8-bit png files that I want to combine (tile) into a single image, what would be the most efficient settings?

So far the strategy I've come up with is

- Use `convert` with `+append` and `-append`
- Use the Q8 (8-bit color) version

Are there other png settings I should consider?  Maybe us uncompressed intermediate files?

Comment: How many images in total do you want to append? What was your exact command line that turned out to be "slow"? How slow was "slow" exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php).  It allows you to join multiple images using one command.